# Can't use application's class in brida

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

I have recently started using **frida** and came across this wonderful tool **brida**, it bridges **BURP** and **Frida**.

Now, the problem is if I try to use `java.lang.String`, it works fine, however if I try to load a class from the android application itself, it gives error like this :

```
**Exception with custom context application**
net.razorvine.pyro.PyroException: [frida.core.RPCException] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.package.name.ClassName" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

The code is like this :

```
contextcustom2: function(message) {
    if(Java.available){
        var hexDecodedInput = hexToString(message);
        var payloadRequestClass = Java.use("com.package.name.ClassName");
        var encryptedPayload = payloadRequestClass.buildPayload(hexDecodedInput);
        return stringToHex(encryptedPayload);
    }
},
```

It is for adding functionality to BRIDA context menu option in BURP.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you follow the official [docs](https://techblog.mediaservice.net/2018/04/brida-a-step-by-step-user-guide/)? Actually I didn't tried [Brida](https://github.com/federicodotta/Brida) yet, but I know it since this presentation of one of its [creators](https://techblog.mediaservice.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/HackInBo-2017-Winter-Edition-Federico-Dotta-Advanced-mobile-penetration-testing-with-Brida-141017.pdf).

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://github.com/federicodotta/Brida/issues/33) for the full insight of what's actually the problem and some other things.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because that class isn't imported. Frida hooks the app, but it can't hook a class that isn't already there. Either find a way to do what you're trying to do with the imported classes ( note enumerateClasses for this matter ), or you can supply this to the script from the outside ( send() ). Note the [docs.](https://frida.re/docs/android/)